# How to add a post build event in MSBuild for .Net 6.0 on Mac?

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, msbuild

How do I need to edit a `*.csproj` file to add a PostBuildEvent on Mac?

I am trying the following but it doesn't work:

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    <Command>echo Hello</Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Then I invoke `dotnet build -f net6.0-maccatalyst` and the event isn't called.

Comment: Is `net6.0-maccatalyst` one of the frameworks defined in `<TargetFrameworks>`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes

Answer (score 1):

The `PropertyGoup` approach as mentioned works, but you can also create a new target like the following if need to add more than just a simple message.

```
<Target Name="MyAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Hello from MyAfterBuild" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>echo Hello</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```